# How to calculate voltage as a function of resistance without knowing the resistance and current

Tags: voltage, current, resistors

Referring to this image below. Is there any way I can calculate VR(R) with just using a resistor in series of 13kohm (I dont think will help) and a power supply of 5V without a given current value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thankyou.

[image]

Comment: You are right: you can't work it out without the current.

Comment: You can't get a number but you can write an equation which is even better.

Comment: Is this school work?

Answer (score 0):

> *Any help would be greatly appreciated.*

$$\dfrac{V_R}{\text{5 volts}} = \dfrac{R}{\text{13000}+R}$$

So, if you don't know \$R\$ then you can't calculate \$V_R\$.

Comment: Thankyou, its been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the current, the voltage across R cannot be determined.

However, by substituting values approaching zero and infinity in the resistor divider formula (the limits of what R could be), you can at least say that:

$$ \text{V}_\text{R} = \frac{\text{R}}{13\text{k} + \text{R}}\cdot 5\text{V} = \frac{\text{0}}{13\text{k} + \text{0}}\cdot 5\text{V} = 0\text{V}$$

$$ \text{V}_\text{R} = \frac{1\text{G}}{13\text{k} + 1\text{G}}\cdot 5\text{V} = 4.99999\text{V}$$

Which is just that \$V_R\$ will be somewhere between 0 to 5V depending on its value.

Of course if you know the value of R (say 1k), then:

$$ \text{V}_\text{R} = \frac{1\text{k}}{13\text{k} + 1\text{k}}\cdot 5\text{V} = 0.357\text{V}$$

Likewise if you know the current (say 100**µA**) through either of these resistors (since they are in series so share the same current), R must be:

$$ \text{R} = \frac{\text{V}}{\text{I}} = \frac{(100\text{µA}\cdot13\text{k}) + (100\text{µA}\cdot \text{R})}{\text{100µA}} = \frac{5\text{V} -(100\text{µA}\cdot13\text{k})}{\text{100µA}} = \frac{5\text{V} - 1.3\text{V}}{\text{100µA}} = \frac{3.7\text{V}}{100\text{µA}} = 37\text{k}\Omega$$

Comment: Thankyou very much for your response, this has been very helpful. When you put the second formula for R approaching infinity, you have put 1G. Is this representing 1 * 10^9? And why did you choose this specifically?

Comment: Yes, the upper limit of R was arbitrarily chosen as 1GΩ because it is a very high value (higher than would normally ever be encountered in the real world) yet is efficient to write.  That is all; could have used 100MΩ, but that is a feasible value for a real device.